# Parsing XML in SQL Server using Procedure "sp_xml_preparedocument" with xml has default namespace failing to parse

Tags: sql-server, xml

Consider the following SQL run on SQL Server. The only difference between these two blocks is that one has the Default Namespace Set. Why does the one with the default namespace fail to parse?

I realize there are other ways to parse xml within sql server. I am just trying to understand the oddity in these two examples explicitly. Any help is appreciated.

```
DECLARE @idoc INT, @doc VARCHAR(1000);   
SET @doc ='  
<ROOT xmlns="Test" xmlns:B="anotherTest" >  
<Customers CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">  
   <Orders CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate=  
           "1996-07-04T00:00:00">  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>  
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
<Customers CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">  
   <Orders CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate=  
           "1996-08-16T00:00:00">  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>  
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
</ROOT>';  
  
--Create an internal representation of the XML document.  
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;   
  
-- SELECT statement as written returns 0 records.  
SELECT    *  
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Customers')   
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;   
GO 


DECLARE @idoc INT, @doc VARCHAR(1000);   
SET @doc ='  
<ROOT xmlns:A="Test" xmlns:B="anotherTest" >  
<Customers CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">  
   <Orders CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate=  
           "1996-07-04T00:00:00">  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>  
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
<Customers CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">  
   <Orders CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate=  
           "1996-08-16T00:00:00">  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>  
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
</ROOT>';  
  
--Create an internal representation of the XML document.  
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;   
  
-- SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.  
SELECT    *  
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Customers')   
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;   

GO
```

Relevant Link:
[Proc sp_xml_preparedocument Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xml-preparedocument-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

SQL Server 2014

Comment: Why use `sp_xml_preparedocument` at all? SQL Server has supported XQuery since 2005.

Comment: This is looking at a legacy system that is using it. We have a project to replace it in the future. But it is failing now do to this proc with xml passed in like the example.

Comment: By Legacy system do you mean it's using SQL Server 2000? I hope not. And if so, you should be including that tag.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky The provided code did show the issue. I will add more descriptive text stating the version, and what I am not understanding.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for taking the time to answer. This is targeting SQL 2014. But it reproducible in SQL 2017. Legacy more in that the code I am inheriting was written targeting SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Then you should be updating said code to use XQuery. As I mentioned SQL Server has supported it since 2005. If you're on 2017 then regardless of the compatibility of the database, you can use XQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first doc has a default namespace so the names, so ROOT and Customers are in the namespace "Test", and the XPath expression "/ROOT/Customers" doesn't match them.  You need to introduce a namespace alias for "Test" to use in your XPath expression.

You do this by providing a dummy XML doc with the alaised namespace declarations as the third argument to sp_xml_preparedocument, like this:

```
DECLARE @idoc INT, @doc VARCHAR(1000);   
SET @doc ='  
<ROOT xmlns="Test" xmlns:B="anotherTest" >  
<Customers CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">  
   <Orders CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate=  
           "1996-07-04T00:00:00">  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>  
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
<Customers CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">  
   <Orders CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate=  
           "1996-08-16T00:00:00">  
      <Order_x0020_Details OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>  
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
</ROOT>';  
  
--Create an internal representation of the XML document.  
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc, N'<dummy xmlns:d="Test"/>';   
  
-- SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.  
SELECT    *  
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/d:ROOT/d:Customers')   
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;   
GO
```